# PreferenceScreen on android studio

Tags: android, xml

Is `PreferenceScreen` still available on Android Studio? I've tried creating an xml folder until res folder and create preference.xml file but it gives me the following error: http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android URI is not registered.
Where should I place this file under?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_key_username"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_username"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_username"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_user" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_key_dbname"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_dbname"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_dbname"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_dbname"  />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_key_api_key"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_api_key"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_api_key"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_api_key" />
    <EditTextPreference
        android:key="pref_key_api_password"
        android:summary="@string/pref_summary_api_password"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_api_password"
        android:defaultValue="@string/default_api_password" />

</PreferenceScreen>
```

[image]

Comment: Could you paste screenshot of your directory structure?

Comment: Added screenshot for your reference :)

Comment: That's wrong. Added answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should not be in values folder. It should be in

```
res\xml\preference.xml
```

Better you should use "Add Android XML" file option in Studio inteaad of manually creating folders and files.